# MongoDB Aggregation to Java

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB Aggregation Query that works fine, but when I use it in java the result is always empty.

The mongoDB query is this:

```
db.series.aggregate({$match : {"group" : "1210"}},{$project : {"leadTime_30" : 1}}, {$unwind : "$leadTime_30"}, {$match : {"leadTime_30.date" : {$gte : ISODate("2014-08-12T22:00:00Z")}}})
```

And I converted in Java to:

```
BasicDBObject matchGroup=new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("group",group));
    BasicDBObject projectSerie= new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject(serie, 1));
    BasicDBObject unwindSerie = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", dollarSerie);
    BasicDBObject matchDate = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject(serieQuery, new BasicDBObject("$gte",stringDate)));


    AggregationOutput output = col.aggregate(matchGroup, projectSerie, unwindSerie, matchDate);
```

For see if the aggregation is empty I do:

```
if (!output.results().iterator().hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Traza: bad aggregation");
}
```

And it always print that. What I`m doing wrong? Thanks for your answers!!

Comment: The value of the variables is:
    group: "1250"
    serie: "leadTime_30"
    dollarSerie: "$leadTime_30"
    serieQuery: "leadTime_30.date"
    stringDate: "2014-08-12T22:00:00Z"

Comment: The dollarSerie part is not a valid BSON object. You need to make it look like your line above.

Comment: I copied bad this line. The code is updated now

Comment: **stringDate** should be a Date Object but not String in your java code, since **$gte** returns `false` when comparing two different types of data.

Comment: How I can get this format? I used that:
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddT:00:00:00Z").parse(stringDate);
But I receive this error : Illegal pattern character 'T'
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please show the full definition of your variable in the code (`group`, `serie`, `dollarSerie`, `serieQuery` and very important: `stringDate`).

If `stringDate` is of the Type `String` it will never match in the comparing against an `ISODate`. To produce an `ISODate` out of the MongoDB Java Driver you need to use a `java.util.Date`. Also `group` must be a `String` and not a Number as in your shell aggregation it is a String.

Using this dateFormat should work. The `T` and `Z` should be added by the convertion of the driver.

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2014-08-12 22:00:00");
```

Comment: The variables are all Strings. i'm gonna prove that you say